# Validación de formulario al instante

Tags: javascript, php

Buen día comunidad.
Quisiera apoyo para hacer una validación de un formulario.
Tengo un registro de inventario pero quiero que cuando escriba el numero de serie me valide si ya existe antes de enviar el formulario

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="NoSerie" class="form-label">No Serie</label>
    <input required type="text" name="NoSerie" class="form-control" id="NoSerie" placeholder="0843642012">
</div>
```

mi tabla se llama producto y el campo NoSerie
Se los agradecería si me ayudan. Se poco de PHP y casi nada de JavaScript

este es el controlador de registro

```
static public function ctrCrearProducto()
    {
        if (isset($_POST["NombreProducto"])) {
            $valor = null;
            $item = null;
            $id= $_POST["NoSerie"];
            $tabla = "producto";
            $respuesta = ModeloInventario::mdlCompararInventario($tabla, $item, $valor, $id);
            foreach ($respuesta as $key => $respuesta) {
                $NoSerieProducto = $respuesta['NoSerie'];
                if ($_POST["NoSerie"] != $NoSerieProducto
                ) {
                    $tabla = "producto";
                    $Status = "Activo";
                    $IDUsuario = "1";
                    $datos = array(
                        "IDSucursal" => $_POST["IDSucursal"],
                        "Categoria" => $_POST["Categoria"],
                        "FechaIngreso" => $_POST["FechaIngreso"],
                        "Condicion" => $_POST["Condicion"],
                        "Factura" => $_POST["Factura"],
                        "Precio" => $_POST["Precio"],
                        "NombreProducto" => $_POST["NombreProducto"],
                        "ModeloCable" => $_POST["ModeloCable"],
                        "ModeloCartucho" => $_POST["ModeloCartucho"],
                        "IDUsuario" => $IDUsuario,
                        "NoSerie" => $_POST["NoSerie"],
                        "Teclado" => $_POST["Teclado"],
                        "Status" => $Status,
                        "Mouse" => $_POST["Mouse"],
                        "ClaveCargador" => $_POST["ClaveCargador"]
                    );

                    $respuesta = ModeloInventario::mdlIngresarProducto($tabla, $datos);
                    if ($respuesta == "ok") {
                        echo "<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Se registro con exito',
                        showConfirmButton: false,
                        timer: 1500});
                        function redireccionar(){
                            window.location.href = 'inventario.php';
                          }
                          setTimeout('redireccionar()', 1500);

                    </script>";
                    }
                } else {

                    echo "<script>

                Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    text: 'Ocurrio un error con los datos ingresados!',
                    
                  });
                        function redireccionar(){
                            window.location.href = 'inventario.php';
                          }
                          setTimeout('redireccionar()', 1500);

                </script>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es mi modelo, intente comparar mi numero de serie pero algo esta pasando que no lo valida y me hace multiplex registros, me imagino que comparando cada uno de los números de serie ya registrados

```
static public function mdlCompararInventario($tabla, $item, $valor, $id)
    {

        if ($item != null) {

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE NoSerie = $id");

            $stmt->bindParam(":" . $item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt->fetch();
        } else {

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE NoSerie = :$id");

            $stmt->execute();

            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }

        $stmt->close();

        $stmt = null;
    }
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Cómo validas si existe o no?... Danos más información y adjunta tu código completo. Recuerda mostrar un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Ya agregue más detalles

Comment: La respuesta corta es, usa `ajax` o `fetch` para hacer peticiones asíncronas al servidor, de esa manera obtienes una respuesta sin necesidad de enviar el formulario ni recargar la pagina. Revisa la documentación de las API o busca ejemplos aquí mismo, en la comunidad.